# Possible Cross Domain Proxy Issues

Tags: 7, nodes, proxies, javascript

My drupalgap app works fine in ripple emulator when I disable the cross domain proxy options. However, when I compile the app and pull out the debug apk and run the app on emulator the main menu and anonymous menu disappear what I am left is with site title and background image. Appreciate if anybody can give me any possible pointers to work on.